# Group an array to match another array

Tags: swift

I have an array of dates that is grouped by months. I am trying to group another array of values so that it matches the first array. Is that possible?

For example:

```
array1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
array2 = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"]
```

I would want the second array to be grouped the same as the first array so that they match:

```
array2 = [["one","two","three"],["four","five","six"]]
```

Comment: What do we know about the first array?  Is it always `[[Int]]`?  Do both arrays have the same numbers of basic elements?

Comment: @vacawama in this case sure, but this is more about the general way of achieving this

Comment: you'll probably need to use `NumberFormatter` to match the number string to integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The evolution of an idea...**

**First, a solution for a 2D array:**

If you know your `array1` is a 2-dimensional array (array of arrays of elements), you can do this by making `array2` into an iterator and using `map` and `compactMap` to replace the elements:

```
let array1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
let array2 = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"]

var iter = array2.makeIterator()

let array3 = array1.map { arr in arr.compactMap { _ in iter.next() }}
print(array3)
```

**Result:**

> ```
> [["one", "two", "three"], ["four", "five", "six"]]
> ```

---

**A more general and generic solution:**

Here is a more general solution that uses a sequence instead of `array2`, that doesn't depend on your knowing ahead of time the layout of `array1` or the types of the values of either the array or the sequence:

```
func remap<S: Sequence>(_ array: [Any], using sequence: S) -> [Any] {
    var iter = sequence.makeIterator()

    func remap(_ array: [Any]) -> [Any] {
        return array.compactMap { value in
            if let subarray = value as? [Any] {
                return remap(subarray)
            } else {
                return iter.next()
            }
        }
    }

    return remap(array)
}
```

**How this works:**

The second array or sequence is turned into an iterator called `iter` which allows us to get the values in order with repeated calls to `iter.next()`.

Then a second recursive version of `remap()` is used to convert `[Any]` into `[Any]` in a depth-first traversal order. `compactMap()` is used to replace elements of the array. While replacing the elements of the array, if the element is another array, it recursively calls `remap()` on that array until it finally gets to values which aren’t arrays. If the element is a non-array element, it replaces it with the `next` value from the iterator which is serving up the elements of the sequence (or second array) in order. We use `compactMap` instead of `map` to handle the fact that `iter.next()` is returning *optional* values because it could run out of values in which case it returns `nil`. In that case, `remap()` will replace the remaining elements with nothing while still maintaining the structure of the first nested array.

**Examples:**

```
// replace Ints with Strings
let array1: [Any] = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]]]
let array2 = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"]

let array3 = remap(array1, using: array2)
print(array3)
```

> ```
> ["one", ["two", "three"], ["four", ["five", "six"]]]
> ```

```
// replace Strings with Ints
let array4: [Any] = ["a", ["b", "c"], [[["d"]], "e"]]
let array5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let array6 = remap(array4, using: array5)
print(array6)
```

> ```
> [1, [2, 3], [[[4]], 5]]
> ```

```
// map letters to numbers starting with 5 using a partial range
print(remap(["a", ["b"], ["c", ["d"]]], using: 5...))
```

> ```
> [5, [6], [7, [8]]]
> ```

```
// using stride to create a sequence of even numbers
let evens = stride(from: 2, to: Int.max, by: 2)
print(remap([["a", "b"], ["c"], [["d"]]], using: evens))
```

> ```
> [[2, 4], [6], [[8]]]
> ```

```
// an example of not enough values in replacement array
print(remap([["a", "b"], ["c"], [["d"]]], using: [1]))
```

> ```
> [[1], [], [[]]]
> ```

Answer (score -3):

You can use numpy.array instead of list, like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr2 = ["one","two","three","four","five","six"]
arr3 = np.array(arr2).reshape(2,3)

arr3
```

Result:

```
array([['one', 'two', 'three'],
       ['four', 'five', 'six']], dtype='<U5')
```

Comment: This question is tagged Swift, not Python.